# Keeping custom figure font size when using print()

Tags: font-size, matlab-figure

I am running a self written script which plots and saves a large number (over 100) of graphs and I have set the axis text to 18pt using

`set(0,'defaultAxesFontSize',18);`

The figures are saved as `.fig` using the `savefig()` command and the font size is correct. But when I save them as `.jpg` (to be included in a LaTeX report) using `print(name, '-djpeg')` the font size is the regular default size (guessing about 10pt). If I open one of the `.fig` files and do File > Save as, the resulting `.jpg` file has the desired font size.

How can I solve this in the command line?

EDIT:

I have tried using `saveas(gcf, name, 'jpg')` as well but the result is the same.

EDIT 2:

Here is a minimal example

```
set(0,'defaultAxesFontSize',18);

x = linspace(0, 2*pi);

plot(x, sin(x))
title('Sine')
xlabel('x')
ylabel('y')
legend('y = sin(x)')

fig = strcat('Sine')
savefig(fig)
print(fig, '-djpeg')
```

Tanks
Kajsa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to set the paper position mode to auto to make the print the same size as the figure on screen.

This does that for all figures

```
set(0,'defaultAxesFontSize',18);
set(0,'DefaultFigurePaperPositionMode','auto')

x = linspace(0, 2*pi);

figure(1)
plot(x, sin(x))
title('Sine')
xlabel('x')
ylabel('y')
legend('y = sin(x)')

fig = strcat('Sine')
savefig(fig)
print(fig, '-djpeg')
```

Works great.